# Django access current user fields from derived class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I have an extended User class, and then a Patient class inherited from it. After the patient logs in I can get first name using `request.user.first_name` but how can I get the value of `address`?

**models.py:**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    is_Patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    object = UserManager()

class Patient(User):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Patients'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. We have to use lowercase letters so that:

```
request.user.patient.address
```

Instead of:

```
request.user.Patient.address
```